# Concisely Insert/Update/Delete Enumerable Child Entities using Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC application and I have a "Report" object that has related enumerables such as schedules and comments. Using AutoMapper, it has been easy to convert from a report entity to a View Model and back, but I have issues when I try to save the Report object (mapped to an existing entity from a view model) back to the database.

More specifically, I can't seem to concisely update existing entities, insert new entities, and delete old entities using automapper. For instance whenever I map schedules from the view model to a report entity, it deletes the existing schedules and then creates new ones (with incremented indexes). This is my code:

```
public class ScheduleViewModel
{
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ReportViewModel
{
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
    public List<ScheduleViewModel> Schedules { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        dbContext db = new dbContext();
        Report original = db.Reports.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ReportID == ReportID);

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ReportViewModel, Report>();
        });

        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        mapper.Map(this, original);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My Report object has a relational key (and a "Schedules" navigational property), so everything is mapped successfully from my view model to the "original" Report. New schedules have a ScheduleID of 0, since they haven't been assigned, and they get added to the database using the auto-increment, which is what I want. The existing schedules maintain their ScheduleID when mapped to the "original" report object, but then recieve incremented IDs once SaveChanges is called.

As I understand it, I'm attaching new schedules to the context whether or not the view model ID properties match the primary key in the database (in this case it is a composite of ReportID and ScheduleID). Is there a clean way, using some sort of ForMember(report => report.Schedules), expression that makes Entity Framework understand to not destroy my existing entities if a View Model object can map to an existing Key?

I am looking for something that functions similar to the code below, but since I will have many enumerable properties attached to my report objects, I don't want to maintain these sections for each:

```
foreach (Schedule schedule in db.Schedules.Where(s => s.ReportID == this.ReportID))
{
    ScheduleViewModel svm = this.Schedules.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ScheduleID == schedule.ScheduleID);

    //Update Existing
    if (svm != null)
        db.Entry(schedule).CurrentValues.SetValues(svm);

    //Delete Missing
    else
        db.Entry(schedule).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
}

//Insert New
foreach(ScheduleViewModel svm in this.Schedules.Where(s => s.ScheduleID == 0))
{
    svm.ReportID = ReportID;
    Schedule schedule = new Schedule() {};
    db.Schedules.Add(schedule);
    db.Entry(schedule).CurrentValues.SetValues(svm);
}
```

Comment: [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not currently possible with AutoMapper. Instead of mapping individual entities, AutoMapper destroys the existing entity collection and creates a new one with the same properties. I'm sure that works fine for some applications, but with Entity Framework's change tracking it is telling the database to delete the existing records and insert new ones, with new IDs. Unfortunately it seems collections have to be mapped individually/manually using the method I posted in my original question. Rather than repeating that for every collection, though, I wrote a generic handler that will map a model collection to an entity collection using a specified key -- without destroying the entities:

```
public void UpdateEntitySet<T>(IEnumerable<object> models, IEnumerable<T> entities, string key) where T : class
{
    Dictionary<object, T> entityDictionary = new Dictionary<object, T>();

    foreach(T entity in entities)
    {
        var entityKey = entity.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(entity);
        entityDictionary.Add(entityKey, entity);
    }

    if (models != null)
    {
        foreach (object model in models)
        {
            var modelKey = model.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(model);
            var existingEntity = entityDictionary.SingleOrDefault(d => Object.Equals(d.Key, modelKey)).Value;

            if (existingEntity == null)
            {
                var newEntity = db.Set<T>().Create();
                db.Set<T>().Add(newEntity);
                db.Entry(newEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
            }
            else
            {
                db.Entry(existingEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
                entityDictionary.Remove(entityDictionary.Single(d => Object.Equals(d.Key, modelKey)).Key);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < entityDictionary.Count; i++)
        db.Entry(entityDictionary.ElementAt(i).Value).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

If you have a composite key, you'll have to modify the code a little, otherwise you can ignore the mapping with AutoMapper and then use the method above like so:

```
IEnumerable<Schedule> ScheduleEntities = db.Set<Schedule>().Where(s => s.ReportID == ReportID);
UpdateEntitySet<Schedule>(ScheduleViewModels, ScheduleEntities, "ScheduleID");
```

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu He added a comment, not an answer -- and it was a link to a library with no explanation. I'm certainly not going to use 2 separate libraries to map DTOs. My question is in regards to AutoMapper, the shortcomings of which were detailed in my answer.

Comment: That's because that has been discussed many times before. I'm reasonably sure that library does a better job then the adhoc code you have here.

Comment: I've been reading about this for weeks and that project is certainly not the accepted standard. Most people just map collections individually/manually. Why on earth would I add a dependency to this library and rely on another developer to maintain something I can manage myself with one function? What do you mean by "better job"? This works perfectly for my situation, but go ahead and knock yourself out with some benchmarks if you think that makes even the slightest difference to me.

Comment: @BrandonChurch Because this AutoMapper add-on library is addressing exactly your issue. And it does it in a good way. While your code is... just bad. If we ignore the obvious issues with treating everything as `string` and using intesilvely reflection, the 2 (!) `foreach (T entity in db.Set<T>())` will read the **whole** table from the database - no one would ever use such code in production.

Comment: @IvanStoev Too much reflection? How do you think that library maps generic classes? Magic? I'm fully aware it's reading the whole table. People would have to add their own constraints to the sets based on their own object models, and I'm not going to add more generic handlers for that. I agree with you on the string comment, I was having issues doing an equality check on GetValue objects even when the property type/value was the same and have yet to figure out why. I only posted this code to show how you can work with dbSet generics to reduce redundant collection mapping.

Comment: @BrandonChurch No magic of course. But the production libraries use cached expressions and (one time compiled) delegates, so the reflection is reduced to the minimum.

Comment: @IvanStoev What's to prevent someone from applying the same here? I'm sure the library is great, but I don't want to add the dependency. If it doesn't stay on the current .Net framework, that's an issue. When my application is audited, dependencies are scrutinized. If a new developer works on my application, it's another black box to investigate. Once I figure out the equality check I will edit my answer. If you have any other suggestions I will be happy to incorporate those too -- but I'm sure we can provide a better example of the concepts than a GitHub link in a comment.